# PHPExcel: Setting column width based on column number

Tags: phpexcel

i am using PHPExcel & searched a lot to get the result for setting the column width based on column number. I found results based on column id's but couldnt find any result for setting width based on column number. I am asking to know about, based on column number. What i tried before is

```
 $length = strlen($tempval);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($dataColumn)->setWidth($length+10);
```

But it is hsowing me fatel error.. what supposed to be the right one??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Column ID from the Column Number using the
`PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()`, pass the column index (e.g. `32` or `7`) and it will return the column ID (like `AG` or `H`).

There is also a corresponding `PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString()` static method.... pass the column ID (like "AB") as an argument, and it will return the column number (e.g. `28`).

---

Note that (for historic reasons) `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` is 0-based (`0` will return `A`, `1` will return `B`, etc); whereas `PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString()` is 1-based (`A` will return `1`, `B` will return `2`, etc).